# Pandas adding difference rows by groups

Tags: pandas, row, difference

I have a given df:

```
ID Name  Alias  Ttl Value 
1  abc    A     10    2
1  abc    B     10    3
1  abc    C     10    1
1  ijk    A      5    2
1  ijk    B      5    2
2  ijk    A      5    2
2  ijk    B      5    2
```

I want insert a "leftover" row for each group by ID and Name.  What I mean is this:

Output:

```
ID Name  Alias  Ttl Value 
1  abc    A     10    2
1  abc    B     10    3
1  abc    C     10    1
1  abc    Z     10    4   <---10 - (2+3+1)
1  ijk    A      5    2
1  ijk    B      5    2
1  ijk    Z      5    1   <---5 - (2+2)
2  ijk    A      5    2
2  ijk    B      5    2   
2  ijk    Z      5    1   <---5 - (2+2)
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  Is it possible in python?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.append((df.groupby(['ID','Name']).\
             apply(lambda x : x['Ttl'].head(1)-
          sum(x['Value']))).\
               reset_index().\
                 drop('level_2',1).rename(columns={'Ttl':'Value'})).\ 
                    fillna({'Alias':'Z'}).\
                       sort_values(['ID','Name']).\
                            ffill()
Out[446]: 
  Alias  ID Name   Ttl  Value
0     A   1  abc  10.0      2
1     B   1  abc  10.0      3
2     C   1  abc  10.0      1
0     Z   1  abc  10.0      4
3     A   1  ijk   5.0      2
4     B   1  ijk   5.0      2
1     Z   1  ijk   5.0      1
5     A   2  ijk   5.0      2
6     B   2  ijk   5.0      2
2     Z   2  ijk   5.0      1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need.  :)

Comment: @TylerNG yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.concat`, `groupby`, `agg`, and `eval`:

```
(pd.concat([df,
           df.groupby(['ID','Name'])['Ttl','Value']
             .agg({'Ttl':'first','Value':'sum'})
             .eval('Value = Ttl - Value').reset_index()])
  .sort_values(['ID','Name'])
  .fillna('Z'))
```

Output:

```
  Alias  ID Name  Ttl  Value
0     A   1  abc   10      2
1     B   1  abc   10      3
2     C   1  abc   10      1
0     Z   1  abc   10      4
3     A   1  ijk    5      2
4     B   1  ijk    5      2
1     Z   1  ijk    5      1
5     A   2  ijk    5      2
6     B   2  ijk    5      2
2     Z   2  ijk    5      1
```

Comment: Not sure why I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'  but the logic here is very simple and helpful

Comment: Maybe pandas version?   You have a good answer with Wen.  Happy coding.